# Cannot remove user from a group

Tags: permission, user-account, settings

I would like to remove a user, "name", from the staff group.

Running `dseditgroup -o edit -d name -t user staff` seems to have no effect.

Why doesn't this work and what should I do differently in order to successfully remove the user from the group?

I am an admin account and "name" is a standard account. I am running Ventura 13.2.

When I add `-v` it appears that "name" is not actually a member of the group:

```
dsAttrTypeStandard:GroupMembership -
        root
```

But if I do `dsmemberutil checkmembership -U name -G staff` it says "user is a member of the group"

Comment: Does adding `-v` offer any clues?

Comment: @nohillside maybe. Updated the question.